# Touchpad suddenly stopped working on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, 17.04, synaptics

I've been using Kubuntu 17.04 for a few months now. Today, when I started my computer, the touchpad wasn't working and I have no idea why.

I googled for a while, and found many people having this problem for different reasons, but haven't found any solution that worked for me. It can't be due to new software installations or upgrades, since I didn't do any yesterday (when it worked last). Rebooting my computer today didn't change anything either. I also checked the touchpad toggle button on my laptop with no results.

Apparently the system is recognizing the touchpad:

```
dmesg |grep -i touchpad
[    2.294403] psmouse serio2: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04733/0xa40000/0xa0000/0x0, board id: 0, fw id: 582762
[    2.345807] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input9
[   23.348266] toshiba_acpi: Supported laptop features: hotkeys touchpad usb-sleep-charge cooling-method
```

Here's the output of `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CNF9055                                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here's what I get from `synclient -l`

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1767
    RightEdge               = 5397
    TopEdge                 = 1637
    BottomEdge              = 4451
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 234
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 106
    HorizScrollDelta        = 106
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1                                                                                                                                            
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0                                                                                                                                            
    CornerCoasting          = 0                                                                                                                                            
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1                                                                                                                                            
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0                                                                                                                                            
    MinSpeed                = 1                                                                                                                                            
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75                                                                                                                                         
    AccelFactor             = 0.0374602
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 26
    VertHysteresis          = 26
    ClickPad                = 0
```

I tried running `synclient TouchpadOff=0` but nothing changed.

What else can I check/try? Thanks!

Comment: This is a random idea... could it be that the laptop has a battery swelling issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I'm more stupid than I thought. My laptop has two different buttons to toggle the touchpad (one with Fn+F9 which is what I was trying and a little slightly visible button just over the touchpad itself). Pressing the second button did the trick.

Comment: Not wasting our time.  It answered my question and saved me lots of time.  Lesson learned: don't let cats roam freely on the keyboard.